# JavaScript Executor for weblist element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This code for an element to click using JavaScript Executor

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.linkText("Update")));
```

But I am creating `List<WebElement>` for an element

```
List<WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.className("btnstyle greenbtn"));
text.get(1).click();
```

Is possible JavaScript Executor for web list element to click according to index value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

Easiest way is to make a function and pass your element:

```
public void clickJS(WebElement we) {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);
}
```

Pass your web element like `clickJS(text.get(1))`.

OR you can use it directly:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", text.get(0));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", text.get(1));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", text.get(2));
```

OR like:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
for(WebElement we:text){
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);
}
```

That being said, Using **Javascript is NOT a great option,** if you want to replicate exact human actions.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Update"))` with `text.get(1)`

```
List<WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.className("btnstyle greenbtn"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", text.get(1));
```

`arguments[0]` is receiving the `WebElement` you insert as parameter to the `executeScript` method.

Answer (score 0):

```html
You could write something like this :
WebElement we=driver.findelement(By.xpath("write your xpath of list element .."));

public void clickJS(WebElement we) {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);
}
```